# Puppeteer not working after fresh install TypeError: selector.startsWith is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I just started with Puppeteer. Basically I did the following in my puppeteer directory:
`npm init -y`, `npm install puppeteer`, `touch index.js`, inserted the boilerplate code into `index.js`, and `node index.js`.

The problematic piece of code is:

```js
const n = await page.$("button[data-test-component='StencilReactButton']")
```

and the error I am getting is:

`TypeError: selector.startsWith is not a function` pointing at `GetQueryHandler.js:51`

I am shocked that there are so few results about this on the web regarding Puppeteer. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My node version is v18.14.2

I ended up going with something like

```js
let selector = "button[data-test-componet='StencilReactButton']";
await page.evaluate((selector)) => document.querySelector(selector).click(), selector);
```

Comment: What Puppeteer version are you using? Which OS? Could you share a [mcve]--the full script with URL? Thanks.